# ¿Cómo y donde almacenar datos de un usuario que ha cerrado sesion en Symfony?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, framework

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Symfony. Se trata de un sistema que simula una tienda online. El problema es que al cerrar sesion, pierdo todos los productos que el usuario a añadido a su cesta de compra. Me gustaria que al cerrar sesion y al cambiar de usuario, estos no pierdan el contenido de la sesion.

¿Como puedo lograrlo? No se muy bien como hacerlo ya que estoy aprendiendo Symfony. Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: En ese caso pudieras almacenar la cesta en la base de datos o en el localStorage del navegador, investiga un poco y tráenos algo de código.

Comment: @Francisco lo voy a probar, muchas gracias